# Define regular Time instances, get differences between them and current Time on Android

Tags: java, android, time, comparison

There're some objects that each one has certain constant times repeat daily (i.e. 12:30PM, 14, 16, 18 ...); I want to calculate differences between System current time and each time spot to find the closest one and show the difference too. I am facing 2 quandaries here:

1. How to define those clock detailed times that repeat daily, in Android `Time` class? I just found this format at reference `time.set(4, 10, 2007)`
2. Should I use `compare(Time a, Time b)` to find the closest Time to now? I'm not sure about the details though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Joda date / time library, and specifically the LocalTime class, which represents a time of day that is not tied to a specific date.  See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html

You can use methods of the LocalTime class to convert to a time in the current day, and then compare.

Comment: Thanks, I Do things like this: 
`DateTime now = new DateTime();
  LocalTime object = new LocalTime(17, 05);
  DateTime test = object.toDateTimeToday();
  int diff = now.compareTo(test);`

What's your suggest to to compare current time and all available times for a single object? While loop maybe?

Comment: Yes, I would think that you'd have to loop over all of the 'available' times, compare each, and select the one with the smallest positive difference.

Comment: Thank you. Just a problem: When try to show difference comes from the comparison;  The output is just `1`. Here's the rest of the code:
`String a = Integer.toString(diff);
  TextView timev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
  
  timev.setText(a);`

Comment: how are you doing the comparison?

Comment: As shown in the first comment: `int diff = now.compareTo(test);`

Comment: That's the problem - compareTo just returns -1, 0, or 1 for less than, equals, or greater than. I think you'll have to do something like `long diff = test.getMillis() - now.getMillis()`

Comment: Dear Grey I'm stuck on this for hours now; Defined an array and make a loop to find differences but it gives **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** in logcat. here's th code:
  `DateTime now = new DateTime();
  LocalTime [] aTime = {
    new LocalTime(2, 05),
    new LocalTime(5, 05),
    new LocalTime(00, 05)
  };` (Cont)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < aTime.length; i++) {
   int j;
   DateTime[] today = new DateTime[i]; 
   for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    today[j] = aTime[i].toDateTimeToday();
   }  
   if ((aTime[i].compareTo(aTime[i+1]))!= -1){
    long diff = (today[j].getMillis() - now.getMillis())/ (1000*60);
    String a = Long.toString(diff);
    textView.append(a+"\n");

   }else{
    break;
   }
  }`
  Should I open new question or append this to current question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30359/discussion-between-greybeardedgeek-and-dummybeginner)